# Exponential of matrix if $A^2=A$

Tags: matrices, power-series, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

So the question is: if $A^2=A$ where A is a matrix find $e^A$. I know I should start with series expansion: $$e^A=1+A+ \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} +... $$
but I don't know how to proceed.
Thanks!

Comment: Can the downvoters explain something, please?

Comment: @ajotatxe Indeed, there seems to be unnecessary hostility here.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^2=A$, then $A^3=AA^2=AA=A^2=A$, and in general it follows that $A^n=A$. Thus
$$e^A=I+A+\frac{A}{2!}+\frac{A}{3!}+\cdots=I+A(1+\tfrac{1}{2!}+\tfrac1{3!}+\cdots)=\boxed{I+(e-1)A}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

By induction, we know $A^n = A$ for all $n \geq 1$. Thus \begin{align*} e^A &= I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \cdots  \\ &=I+(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}-1)A \\ &=I+(e-1)A\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!